# Manage cross-platform projects on Github

Tags: mobile, github, cross-platform

I'm looking for a tidy way to manage my cross-platform HTML+JS projects in github.
Here's my typical working process:

1. I complete developing my app for ios
2. I start working on Android platform version
3. I start working on XXXXXXX platform
4. ...

From step 2 and further I come out with:

- commits that can be merged in the Head repository
- commits that can not be merged, so I have at least 2 versions of some of the files that compose the project

My problem is that forking/branching for each platform force me to duplicate changes on the shared part of the project too. Maybe there's something that I'm missing in both branching and forking.

Which method you use to organize your code on github so as to preserve both the differences and the unity of the project?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like branches might be the way to go: create an **android** branch, etc., and if you need to branch those further then create **android/branch1**, **android/branch2** and so forth.

When you need to merge files between branches you might want to use the `git cherry-pick` command to select the commits to merge. I would also probably do this on a temporary local branch before pushing, to make it easy to recover from screw-ups!